# Is it correct to reference static ServiceConnection from other activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I'm starting and binging my Service at Main activity:

```
public static MyServiceConnection serviceConnection;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    serviceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
    startService(new Intent(...));
    bindService(new Intent(...), serviceConnection.getServiceConnection(), 0);
}
```

If i will start another activity (without finishing Main) can I use static variable like this:

```
Main.serviceConnection.Method1()
```

Will I get NullReferenceException? For example if OS decides to free some memory and destroy main activity? Is it possible?

Comment: You won't be able to access instance variables of the enclosing Activity. The static variable will not be associated with any instance of the Activity unless you pass it one (bad idea).

Comment: no it is not correct, you're supposed to bind to the service in every activity you wish to use it

Comment: Hm... Am I understanding wrong? It's static variable, so I can access it anywhere. And it should be no problem while instance of Main activity is in memory. No?

Comment: @user2661298 : **"It's static variable, so I can access it anywhere."**. Don't treat the Android `Activity` class as if it is a standard Java class - it's not. Most Java classes are passive (they don't do anything until you tell them to). An `Activity` has a 'life' - it's created, started, resumed, running, paused, stopped, destroyed. Because of this, you have no guarantee as to which state an `Activity` is in if you attempt to access any of it's variables or methods from any other app component, e.g., another `Activity`. In short, an `Activity` should be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to reference static ServiceConnection from other activity?

No. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding):

> You should usually pair the binding and unbinding during matching bring-up and tear-down moments of the client's lifecycle. For example:
>
> - If you only need to interact with the service while your activity is visible, you should bind during onStart() and unbind during onStop().
> - If you want your activity to receive responses even while it is stopped in the background, then you can bind during onCreate() and unbind during onDestroy(). Beware that this implies that your activity needs to use the service the entire time it's running (even in the background), so if the service is in another process, then you increase the weight of the process and it becomes more likely that the system will kill it.

Please allow each component to bind to the service itself.

> I'm starting and binging my Service at Main activity:

Please delete the `static` keyword. Please use a `ServiceConnection` only in the component that bound to the service. If you have other components, they too can bind to the service themselves.

> Will I get NullReferenceException?

Quite possibly. For example, while you *think* that you are going to "start another activity (without finishing Main)", there is no requirement that the "Main" activity stay around. If Android terminates your process (after you move to the background) and the user returns to you via the recent-tasks list, your second activity may be created before "Main" is in the new process.

Please allow your second activity to bind to the service itself. Or, do not use bound services.